# What is the difference between multicore and concurrent programming

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, multicore, concurrent-programming

Can anyone help me out I am working on a presentation and would like to include a bit about - 'The difference between multicore and concurrent programming', I have googled a bit but not turning up many good descriptions, any help appreciated! :)

Thanks,

Eamonn

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's the difference between parallel and multicore programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257054/whats-the-difference-between-parallel-and-multicore-programming)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Concurrent** *(occurring or existing simultaneously)* implies that different code **MAY** execute at the exact same cycle. It means that things can **possibly** happen in parallel if multiple processors or a processor with multiple cores is available and the program is crafted correctly. Just adding threads does not imply concurrent execution.

The reason I say **MAY** and **possibly** is that anytime the programs separate threads need to share volatile/mutable state, other threads that need access to that state can not continue executing and will have to wait their turn to access that state, and things start happening serially again.

Typically this is implemented in a single program as more than one thread executing code concurrently at the same exact cycle as another thread, given that there is no resource contentions as listed above. This requires multiple physical processors or cores. Other models run multiple heavyweight OS processes that can execute concurrently.

**Concurrent programming is very hard to do correctly with mutable shared state.**

> You can write a **concurrent** program
>   that runs **serially** on a single single
>   core processor, but scales up to
>   execute more things at the same time
>   when more processors or cores, or even
>   multiple processors with multiple
>   cores is present.
>
> You can also cause single threaded programs to **appear concurrent** on a multi-core / multi-processor system if they can operate on independent ranges of input data at the same time. Example: a single threaded 3D rendering program can on a dual core machine can run 2 separate instances the first rendering all the odd frames and the second rendering all the even frames. As long as they don't try to share any mutable resources.

**Multi-core** means that a single CPU has multiple Processor cores that can execute threads or processes concurrently and typically appears as multiple processors to mainstream operating systems.

> It does **NOT** imply that programs that are single threaded gain any concurrency behaviors or benefits from the additional processor cores available.

Comment: "Concurrent programming is very hard to do correctly with mutable shared state". The Cilk examples are a good counter example. Concurrent programming with shared mutable state can be hard but it is often essential in multicore parallel programming.

Answer (score 2):

Concurrent Programming is more broad - it just refers to writing software that will run "concurrently" - ie: more than one thing will happen at a time.

"Multi-core" programming is really referring to a specific subset of concurrent programming, in which you are targetting multiple available CPU cores on a specific machine.  This is the most common form of concurrent programming (typically single process running on a single computer), but still only one form of concurrent programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can do concurrent programming on a machine that has only a single CPU core.  The operating system provides the illusion that more than one thread is running at the same time, it rapidly switches back-and-forth between them.

A machine with multiple cores simply needs to this context switching less often since two threads can run at the same time on two cores.  It is only a bit special because threading bugs can make your life difficult much quicker.  The odds that two threads try to access a shared memory location at the same time is much higher.

Comment: you can not do concurrent programming on a single core CPU, you can do asynchronous programming, but a single core CPU can only do one thing at a time, what you are describing is **time slicing** which by definition is **not** concurrent.

Comment: That's nonsense.  The concurrency bugs you get from a single core are *exactly* the same.  Threads are scheduled by a hardware interrupt that doesn't give beans about program state.  Odd, you look old enough to have had to debug such a bug.

Comment: only one thing can happen exactly at the same time on a single core CPU, this is dictated by the laws of physics. doing more than one thing at a time for very short periods of time is **not** concurrent, because they are **not** happening **concurrently**. [define concurrent - adjective
existing, happening, or done at the same time.](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=define%20concurrent) you do not get to make up a new definition of concurrent. Also concurrent does not imply shared state either, you seem to be conflating a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, multi-core is an attribute of the processor chip in your computer. Multi core means it has got multiple processing cores. There are several types of multi-processor computers: the old style super computers with thousands of computers connected via ethernet, systems with more than processors (like 2 Pentium 4s), and contemporary multi-core systems where every processor package has multiple processing cores 9like Intel i7). The third type is often called multi-core of Chip Multiprocessor (CMP).

Concurrent programming is an attribute of software. Concurrent programming is about writing code which has is split into multiple tasks that can execute concurrently if processors are available. While concurrent programs do leverage multi-core, concurrent programming is broader in two dimensions:

1. Concurrent programs can run on a single core or multiple cores.
2. Concurrent programs can be used on any type of multi-processors I mentioned above.

Thus, to summarize:

Concurrent programming is about software that can use multiple processors if available. those processors can be on the same chip (multi-core or Chip Multiprocessor) or on different chips (often known as SMP). You can have systems where you can put two multi-core chips in the same system making it a CMP and an SMP at the same time. Concurrent programming will work for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Concurrent programming** regards operations that appear to overlap and is primarily concerned with the complexity that arises due to non-deterministic control flow. The quantitative costs associated with concurrent programs are typically both throughput and latency. Concurrent programs are often IO bound but not always, e.g. concurrent garbage collectors are entirely on-CPU. The pedagogical example of a concurrent program is a web crawler. This program initiates requests for web pages and accepts the responses concurrently as the results of the downloads become available, accumulating a set of pages that have already been visited. Control flow is non-deterministic because the responses are not necessarily received in the same order each time the program is run. This characteristic can make it very hard to debug concurrent programs. Some applications are fundamentally concurrent, e.g. web servers must handle client connections concurrently. [Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/), F# [asynchronous workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233250.aspx) and Scala's [Akka](http://akka.io/) library are perhaps the most promising approaches to highly concurrent programming.

**Multicore programming** is a special case of parallel programming. Parallel programming concerns operations that are overlapped for the specific goal of improving throughput. The difficulties of concurrent programming are evaded by making control flow deterministic. Typically, programs spawn sets of child tasks that run in parallel and the parent task only continues once every subtask has finished. This makes parallel programs much easier to debug than concurrent programs. The hard part of parallel programming is performance optimization with respect to issues such as granularity and communication. The latter is still an issue in the context of multicores because there is a considerable cost associated with transferring data from one cache to another. Dense matrix-matrix multiply is a pedagogical example of parallel programming and it can be solved efficiently by using Straasen's divide-and-conquer algorithm and attacking the sub-problems in parallel. [Cilk](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/cilk/) is perhaps the most promising approach for high-performance parallel programming on multicores and it has been adopted in both Intel's [Threaded Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) and Microsoft's [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) (in .NET 4).